# how do i set the pool size of message driven beans in tomee?

Tags: ejb, message-driven-bean, apache-tomee

I have 3 types of MDBs in my TomEE 1.6.0 app.

I'd like to set the max pool size of one of them to a certain value, without affecting the others.

Tomee docs give instructions on how to set for a EJB type (http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html), e.g.

```
<Container id="Foo" type="MESSAGE">
    InstanceLimit 10
</Container>
```

but not for a specific MDB.

how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your MDB with different types have different interfaces.
And then you can define multiple MDB Containers with different IDs respectively.

Example:

```
<Container id="TypeA" type="MESSAGE">
    InstanceLimit 10
    messageListenerInterface your.interface.typeA
</Container>
<Container id="TypeB" type="MESSAGE">
    InstanceLimit 8
    messageListenerInterface your.interface.typeB
</Container>
```

Comment: message listener interface usually is javax.jms.MessageListener . Can it be any interface that extends it?

Comment: Try using `@MessageDriven(messageListenerInterface=...)`